# Reading and Writing UTF-8 from Query String PHP

Tags: php, utf-8

I need to be able to pass music sharp and flat symbols around in a query string and also display in a utf-8 browser. The displaying part is straight-forward by using html entity representations for sharp and flat symbols.

```
Flat -  &#9837;
Sharp - &#9839;
```

It's the passing around of this data that has me stumped.

Let's take the chord symbol B flat: B♭
It's representation with HTML entities is: `B&#9837;`

**Client**
To pass it I url-encode it: `B%26%239837%3B`
Then I feed that in my query string: `?lookup=B%26%239837%3B`

**Server**
Read it: `$r = urldecode($_GET['lookup']);`
Display it: `echo $r;`
Just get B

**So then I tried:**

Read it: `$r = $_GET['lookup'];`
Display it: `echo $r;`
Just get B

Also the raw request just shows B.

How do I pass this type of url-encoded html entity around correctly in the query string?

Comment: php urldecodes for you when it populates $_GET. You shouldn't need to decode again.

Comment: get same result either way...weird

Comment: The only thing PHP code may need to do is `$r = html_entity_decode($_GET['lookup'], ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');`. Or don't use the HTML entity is you use utf-8, and use the plain value in text, the url_encoded value (`B♭` => `B%E2%99%AD`)

Comment: +1 for well structured question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be more straight-forward if you used actual UTF-8 encoded characters instead of HTML entities.

`B%26%239837%3B` is the URL encoded version of `B&#9837;`. `B&#9837;` is the HTML entity representation of "B♭", it is *not* "UTF-8". What you want is `B%E2%99%AD`, which is the URL-encoded UTF-8 representation of "B♭". If you'd do `$_GET['lookup']` on *that*, you'd get the UTF-8 encoded string "B♭".

You should keep everything in UTF-8 front to back. Please see [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) and possibly [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) for details.

Comment: I actually disagree with the idea that every programmer needs to know about utf-8. Unless you're specifically converting between character sets, just use utf-8 everywhere and be done with it. http://www.utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: Well, certainly. That still means you need to know what UTF-8 is and how PHP handles it. The article also says what you need to know about character sets, not what everyone needs to know about UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$bSharp = "&#9839";
echo "<a href='filename.php?bSharp=".urlencode(htmlentities($bSharp))."'>pass it</a>";


//filename.php
echo html_entity_decode(urldecode($_GET['bSharp']));
```